# Что за аргументы в конструкторе Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

Объясните, пожалуйста, в файле контроллера OrdersController:

```
use App\Repositories\OrderRepository;

public function __construct(OrderRepository $orders)
{
  $this->orders = $orders;
}
```

что здесь OrderRepository? Класс, интерфейс? И почему здесь он так пишется в аргументе конструктора вместе со своим же объектом? В нативном php не видел такого

Comment: боюсь Вам нужно почитать за ООП и после этого начинать работу с фреймворками...
класс это или интерфейс вы можете посмотреть зайдя в `OrderRepository` по ключевому слову перед названием

Comment: Этот пример я нашел в документации, а самого orderrepository там нет. И я прекрасно знаю,что такое класс и интерфейс. Мне просто нужно разъяснение конкретного примера

Comment: Хорошо, тогда могу посоветовать Вам не ожидать, что в документации будет описано ВСЕ для конкретного примера. Попробуйте абстрагироваться от реализаций элементов, используемых в документации и попробуйте сосредоточится на описываемой фиче.

Comment: Почитай документацию сначала, особенно раздел про сервис-контейнер. Это так называемое внедрение зависимостей. А если в нативном php такого не видел - это php7 с типизированными параметрами методов